# create span tag include &times; with javascript

Tags: javascript

would you please help me about this:
i wanna make below syntax in Html by javaScript but java doesn't change `&times;` to 'x' (multiplication symbol)

```
 **<span class="close">&times;</span>**
```

my Js codes are :

```
 let closeModal = document.createElement('span');
            closeModal.textContent =' &times;'
        closeModal.classList.add('close');
```

but they don't work and `&times;` does not convert to 'x'

Comment: @Pointy `&times;` is an [HTML entity](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D7). and should be converted to a multiplication symbol.  But not if it's set as `textContent` -- only if it's set as HTML (via `innerHTML`, perhaps).  Minor facepalm question that Mina has answered correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `innerHTML` instead so it can be parsed to `x`, as textContent will add it as a raw string.

```js
 let closeModal = document.createElement('span');
 closeModal.innerHTML =' &times;'
 document.body.appendChild(closeModal)
```